# assistance with rebinding json to knockout model

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I a newbie to knockout and need some help.

I have a mvc asp.net page and when it loads I make a client side call to controller action that returns json, which I create a view model from and bind it to some markup with knockout.

This is some sample code:

Javascript

```
  var CartViewModel = function (d) {

    var self = this,
        showCartInner = function () {
            // code to show a container
        },
        hideCart = function () {
            // code to hide a container
        };

    self.showCart = function () {  
        showCartInner();
    };

    ko.mapping.fromJS(d, {}, self);

    self.hasItems = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.NumberOfItems() > 0;
    });

    self.count = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.NumberOfItems();
    });

    self.qualified = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.Qualified().length > 0;
    });

    return self;
};

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("/getcart", function (data) {
        ko.applyBindings(new CartViewModel(data), window.document.getElementById("cart"));
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="cart">
<div style="display: none;" data-bind="css: { content: !hasItems() }">
empty Cart
</div>

<div style="display: none;" data-bind="css: { content: hasItems() }">
    <span class="loading">
      Look at your items
    </span>
</div>

<div style="display: none;" id="hidden_menu">
    <div id="hidden_cart">
        <div class="cart-item">
            <div class="thumb-img inline">
                <img data-bind="attr: { src: Product.Image, alt: Product.Name }" />
            </div>
            <div class="product-desc inline">
                <span class="name" data-bind="text: Product.Name"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="product-price" data-bind="text: Product.Price"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="cart-offers" data-bind="visible: qualified()">
            <div class="triangle-up-gray"></div>

            <div class="cart-offer" data-bind="visible: qualified()">
                <div id="qualified" data-bind="foreach: { data : Qualified }">
                    <div class="cart-offer-desc" data-bind="text: Description"></div>
                    <a class="cart-offer-action" data-bind="href: Url">View More</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the page loads a call is made to retrieve a shopping cart and bound to markup, see above.

Now when a user updates their cart on the page via a call to a controller action, returned from it is the same json object. At this point I want to update my markup with the new json object.

What changes do I need to make to above to achieve this? How can I pass the json object and not have to reapply bindings and that the markup shows the changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could again call ko.mapping.fromJS

```
var viewModel = null;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $.getJSON("/getcart", function (data) {
        viewModel = new CartViewModel(data);
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel, window.document.getElementById("cart"));
    });

});

function afterSomeUpdate(dataFromServer){
   ko.mapping.fromJS(dataFromServer, viewModel);
}
```

See this link: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html (Example: Using ko.mapping)